# How to ZIP files on gitlab.com before AWS S3 upload

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm new to gitlab's CI/CD (I'm using the gitlab.com version) and what I'm trying to do is to deploy a Python application once it passes all tests to my AMAZON S3 bucket.

The bucket is set-up, the project works and I can do it manually using [Elasticbeanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) and the `eb deploy` command. What I would like to do is that Gitlab will deploy it for me once the tests pass.

The problem is that before I update my S3 bucket I need to zip my files first. My question - what's the easiest way to do it on Gitlab.com? I'm using the shared runners and really a newbie in this topic.

UPDATE: I had to request a shared gitlab.com runner with the particular aws-cli runner to be able to use simple ZIP, like this: `image: napp/docker-aws-cli`. But my question is still valid - is a simple ZIP enough for S3? Do I need to add any dependencies?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6596/54622

Comment: Thanks @1615903 - I was unable to zip it since I was not requesting a gitlab runner with the right image. Is a simple ZIP enough for amazon S3 bucket to understand, unpack and run ?